# Why am I getting a NullPointerException in Android Studio (Fragments)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

So I am trying to pass text in one fragment to main Activity, and have main Activity pass it to another fragment so it can be displayed.

Here is the code of the fragment to send it to main Activity:

```
public class TopFragment extends Fragment{

private static EditText topInput;
private static EditText bottomInput;

FragmentInterface communicate;

public interface FragmentInterface{
    public void sendTheInput(String topText,String bottomText);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment,container,false);

    topInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.topInput);
    bottomInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomInput);
    final Button submitButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    buttonClicked(v);
                }
            }
    );
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        communicate = (FragmentInterface) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
    }
}

public void buttonClicked(View view){

    communicate.sendTheInput(topInput.getText().toString(),bottomInput.getText().toString());

}

}
```

Here is the main activity code:

```
 @Override
    public void sendTheInput(String topText, String bottomText) {
        BottomFragment bottomFrag = (BottomFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottomFragment);
        bottomFrag.setBoxText(topText,bottomText);
    }
```

And here is the bottom fragment code:

```
public class BottomFragment extends Fragment{

private static EditText topTextBox;
private static EditText bottomTextBox;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_fragment,container,false);



    return view;
}

public void setBoxText(String topText, String bottomText){

    topTextBox.setText(topText);
    bottomTextBox.setText(bottomText);

}
}
```

When I run the app, I don't get any runtime errors but I do get this:

```
08-08 13:09:45.820    2241-2241/com.example.vanessaanthony.fragmentreview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vanessaanthony.fragmentreview, PID: 2241
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.vanessaanthony.fragmentreview.BottomFragment.setBoxText(BottomFragment.java:29)
            at com.example.vanessaanthony.fragmentreview.MainActivity.sendTheInput(MainActivity.java:20)
            at com.example.vanessaanthony.fragmentreview.TopFragment.buttonClicked(TopFragment.java:55)
            at com.example.vanessaanthony.fragmentreview.TopFragment$1.onClick(TopFragment.java:36)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 08-08 13:09:56.646    2241-2248/com.example.vanessaanthony.fragmentreview W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.142ms
```

I am a beginner in Android Studio and I don't know why my program won't work. Any answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the two `EditText`s in `BottomFragment` (actually, you should **remove** the `static` there as every fragment has its own edit texts, but that is not the issue):

```
private static EditText topTextBox;
private static EditText bottomTextBox;
```

but you don't give them a value. Android does not know by itself which EditTexts you mean; you have to *find* them using `findViewById`. This is usually done (for Fragments) in `onCreateView`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_fragment,container,false);
    topTextBox = (EditText)view.FindViewById(R.id.topTextBox);
    bottomTextBox = ...
```

just like you did in the `TopFragment`.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed this.